# query paths in Datomic (follow attributes from root to leaves in a tree)

Tags: datomic

I have a tree structure with :node-left and :node-right, which connect entities of the same type until these attributes are not present.

I am interested in querying for paths from the root to the leaves, so that the result would be a vector of type ([root, node1, leaf11] [root, node2, leaf21]).

Answer (score 3):

While you could do this with query, you might also take a look at implementing graph algorithms directly.  This [blog post](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/using-datomic-as-a-graph-database) shows examples of both approaches.